# $Y'''+(Y'')^3=0$?

Tags: calculus

I could not go more. How can we solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I can see that you've reached $y$ (on your picture). *After you've typed your work here*, please ask the question... Do you want your solution checked, for example? What does that mean "I could go no more" when you have $y$ expressed as a function of $x$ (with constants)?

Answer (score 2):

Start by defining $z=y''$ and you have a first order equation.  There will be a solution $z=ax^b$ so plug that in.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z=Y''$.

Then the equation becomes $Z'+Z^3=0$, which gives $X+C=\frac{1}{2Z^2}$

Putting $Y$ back in and rearranging, we have $Y''=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(X+C)}}$

Integrating once: $Y' = \sqrt{2(X+C)}+D$

Integrate again: $Y = \sqrt{\frac89}(X+C)^{\frac32}+Dx+E$